# plotly showing time but I only want date

Tags: javascript, plotly, datetime-format, plotly.js

Trying to use plotly js to make a plot of dates, but for some reason it is showing time and date.

How can I remove time from this plot? Thanks!

```
x = ["2023-02-13", "2023-02-14"];
y = [3, 4];
var trace1 = {
    type: "scatter",
    mode: "lines",
    name: '',
    x: x,
    y: y,
    line: {color: '#17BECF'}
}
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        type: 'date',
    },
    title: '',
};
var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('plotDiv', data, layout);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can specify the [tickformat](https://plotly.com/javascript/tick-formatting/) in the `xaxis` of the `layout` with `tickformat: '%b %d, %Y'` to avoid including the time. And to avoid having the same date repeat on multiple ticks for the same day, we can also set the distance between ticks to be `1 day` using `dtick: 86400000.0` (which will be in units of seconds according to [the documentation](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/?_ga=2.211877140.1095174710.1676255914-1789232123.1675635503#layout-xaxis-dtick)).

The codepen can be viewed [here](https://codepen.io/merillium/pen/Podogzg).

```
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        type: 'date',
        tickformat: '%b %d, %Y',
        dtick: 86400000.0
    },
    title: '',
};
```

[image]